# Display table data based on what users registered (Table Structure)

Tags: codeigniter, html-table, codeigniter-3

I am making a function where I track my users' registration. The users can choose whether they want to register at Red, Blue, Yellow, and Green. I have this table structure in my front end. (Please see the screenshot) My target is how can I do this output based on what registration color they chose? I'm getting confused around my code where I specify the table design should be. (Around $output). I hope someone can help. I'm a newbie. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you, everyone.

[image: This is my target] << this is my target output

**Controller:**

```
function register()
{
    $data = $this->sample->register1();
    $prev = '';
    $next = '';


    $output = '<table style="margin-top: 5px;" id="display">';
    foreach ($data as $f) {


        $next = $f['registercolor'];


        switch ($f['registercolor']) {
            case RED:
                $btn = "bg-danger";
                break;
            case BLUE:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
            case GREEN:
                $btn = "bg-success";
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                $btn = "bg-warning";
                break;
            default:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
        }

        if ($prev === $next || $prev === '' || $next === YELLOW || $next === GREEN) {
             $prev = $next;
                $output .='<tr>';
        } else {
             $prevRe = $nextRe;
               
        }
$output .='<td h-align="top"><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge '.$btn.
            '" style="font-size: 1.6em; margin: .05em; border-radius: 30px;">'.$f['registerID'].'</span></td>';

    }
      $output .= ' </td></table>';
        
        echo json_encode($output);
}
```

https://prnt.sc/1m0owi3 << this is my current output.

I have tried another solution. But i failed to achieve it.

Here's my another solution

Controller:

```
const RED = 'red',
    BLUE = 'blue',
    GREEN = 'green',
    YELLOW = 'yellow';

function register()
{
    $data = $this->sample->register1();
    $prev = '';
    $next = '';


    $output = '<table style="margin-top: -230px;" id="display">';
    foreach ($data as $f) {


        $next = $f['registercolor'];


        switch ($f['registercolor']) {
            case RED:
                $btn = "bg-danger";
                break;
            case BLUE:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
            case GREEN:
                $btn = "bg-success";
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                $btn = "bg-warning";
                break;
            default:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
        }

        if ($prev === $next || $prev === '' || $next === YELLOW || $next === GREEN) {
            $output .= '<td v-align="top"><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge ' . $btn .
                '" style="font-size: 1.6em; margin: .05em; border-radius: 30px;">&#664;</span></td>';
        } else {
            $output .= '</tr><tr><td v-align="top"><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge ' . $btn .
                '" style="font-size: 1.6em; margin: .05em; border-radius: 30px;">&#664;</span></td>';
        }
    }
    // prevent change from same color like this case : RED -> YELLOW -> RED
    if ($next !== YELLOW && $next !== GREEN) {
        $prev = $next;
    }
    $output += '</tr></table>';
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

And this is the output of what I've tried: https://prnt.sc/1m0owi3

Answer (score 1):

that answer is mine. At that time I forgot to arrange the result by column not by row. You can check out the source below.

```
    $data = $this->sample->register1();
    $res = array();
    $prev = '';
    $next = '';

    $output = '<table id="display">';
    $current = 0;
    $res[$current] = array();

    foreach ($data as $f) {
        $next = $f['registercolor'];
        switch ($f['registercolor']) {
            case RED:
                $btn = "bg-danger";
                break;
            case BLUE:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
            case GREEN:
                $btn = "bg-success";
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                $btn = "bg-warning";
                break;
            default:
                $btn = "bg-primary";
                break;
        }

        if ($prev == $next || $prev == '' || $next == YELLOW || $next == GREEN) {
        } else {
            $current++;
            $res[$current] = array();
        }
        $res[$current][] = $btn;
        // prevent change from same color like this case : RED -> YELLOW -> RED
        if ($next != YELLOW && $next != GREEN) {
            $prev = $next;
        }
    }

    $max = count($res[0]);
    foreach ($res as $btn) {
        if (count($btn) > $max) {
            $max = count($btn);
        }
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $output .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($res as $btn) {
            if (array_key_exists($i, $btn)) {
                $output .= '<td v-align="top"><span data-toggle="tooltip" class="badge ' . $btn[$i] .
                    '" style="font-size: 1.6em; margin: .05em; border-radius: 30px;">&#664;</span></td>';
            } else {
                $output .= '<td v-align="top"></td>';
            }
        }
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is not really good because currently I have to use 3 iterations. I'll update if I find out a better one

Comment: Thank you, i will try your suggestion and keep you updated. If it's okay for you. Thanks again.